# How to convert x-www-form-urlencoded to json with Python (Django)

Tags: python, json, django, x-www-form-urlencoded

From api i recive x-www-form-urlencoded data.

```
data = 'leads%5Bstatus%5D%5B0%5D%5Bid%5D=29078079'
```

when i try to convert it with `urllib.parse.parse_qs` or `urllib.parse.unquote`
i got a dict like

```
{
    "leads[status][0][id]": [
        "29078079"
    ]
}
```

how can i convert it to normal json or dict ?
like this

```
{
    "leads": [
       "id": "29078079"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The string parsed correctly. So the question is not so much how you can get a 'normal' dict, rather how you can alter the dict key:

```
dictionary = { "leads[status][0][id]": [ "29078079" ] }
dictionary['leads'] = dictionary.pop(list(dictionary)[0])
```

Alternatively you could create the dict manually:

```
dictionary =  {data[:5]:[data.split('=')[-1]]}
```